How to distribute a neutralinojs project for linux without libwebkit2gtk version hell
I have a (finally!) working neutralinojs project that I would like to distribute for linux.  However, when I follow build instructions, when I get won't run unless the new machine has the same libwebkit2gtk version I had when I gave the neu build --release command.  Is there any way around this?
I tried moving the .zip file produced by the build command, and I also tried the scripts at https://github.com/hschneider/neutralino-build-scripts.git ... both had the same issue.
